# Theano TypeError

Tags: numpy, theano, lasagne, nolearn

I am reading jpg images and then reshaping them into a tensor. I am casting the images as float32:

```
def load(folder,table):
X=[]

train = pd.read_csv(table)

for i,img_id in enumerate(train['Image']):

    img = io.imread(folder+img_id[2:])

    X.append(img)

X = np.array(X)/255.
X = X.astype(np.float32)
X = X.reshape(-1, 1, 225, 225)
return X
```

However, I am getting this error

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "/Users/mas/PycharmProjects/Whale/nolearn_convnet/Zahraa5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nolearn/lasagne/base.py:435"  at index 1(0-based)', 'TensorType(int32, vector) cannot store a value of dtype float32 without risking loss of precision. If you do not mind this loss, you can: 1) explicitly cast your data to int32, or 2) set "allow_input_downcast=True" when calling "function".', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],

       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [cross-post to the theano-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/ZEafOobLFes).

Doug provided an answer there:

> The theano variable you are using is defined as integer, but you
>   passed in a float, hence the error 'TensorType(int32, vector) cannot
>   store a value of dtype float32...'.  You can either modify your data
>   loading code to cast it as int32, or change the symbolic variable to
>   something that supports float32.

So somewhere you have a line that looks something like:

```
x = T.ivector()
```

or

```
x = T.vector(dtype='int32')
```

It looks like you need to change this to something like

```
x = T.tensor4()
```

where the `dtype` has been changed to equal `theano.config.floatX` and the dimensionality as been changed to 4 to match the 4-dimensional nature of `X`.

Comment: The problematic variable is X as described in the code. I meant by tensor a 4D variable bumpy array. @DanielRenshaw

Comment: Response on theano-users mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't figure it out, I had a similar error and here's how I fixed it:
Cast your y as int32. The x values can be floatx, but the y MUST be int32 in nolearn for classification.